# What is this variable in the Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

So here is a Makefile I have been given, with comment I have added.

```
MF= Makefile_c  #name of the makefile
CC= cc          #compiler to use
CFLAGS= -g      #flags to use
LFLAGS= -lm     #flags to use after the thingy
EXE=    hello   #name to give the executable
INC= \          # ??? What's this for ???
#   No user-defined include files at present - list here if required.
# name of the source file
SRC= \
    hello.c

#delete default suffix
.SUFFIXES:
#define the suffixes we are interested in
.SUFFIXES: .c .o
OBJ=    $(SRC:.c=.o)    # names to give the object files
#The .o files depend on the .c files. Compile the object files.
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

all:    $(EXE)    #The output is the executable

$(OBJ): $(INC)    #The objects depend on whatever INC is

# The executable depends on the object files. build it from the object files.
$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LFLAGS)

# ??? the object files depend on the makefile???
$(OBJ): $(MF)

# remove any old executables or object files.
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(EXE) core
```

I am still learning about makefiles so please correct me if I have misidentified anything. The makefile works fine But I want to adapt it to work with my program that has multiple files and header files. I suspect that the variable `$INC` will somehow make this possible, but so far my attempts to use it have not worked.

For now I would like to understand what this makefile is trying to do, cn you tell me what `$INC` is for?

Comment: INC is a list of directories with the additional include files.  For the GCC https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html For MS VC++ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx

Comment: [Might be helpful](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)

Comment: @Olaf It's not about the syntax of makefiles. It's about the semantics of this particular makefile, which is used for building a C program.

Comment: @TormundGiantsbane good link, should probably have included it in my answer!

Answer (score 5):

> The makefile works fine But I want to adapt it to work with my program that has multiple files and header files. I suspect that the variable $INC will somehow make this possible

Unfortunately, no. The `\` is just a line continuation, so you can write content for the variable in the next line. It's empty here. This is just a very simple (and ancient!) approach for dependencies: List them yourself. The intention is to list all files your C source file `#includes` there, so `make` will rebuild when any of these included files change.

There are much advanced patterns, `gcc` (and other compilers) allow to do automatic dependency information for `make`, but this is out of scope for this question. (*)

As for building with multiple source files, this Makefile already supports it, again using an "ancient" way, a suffix rule. It automatically considers all `.c` files in your directory part of your final program.

---

(*) As mentioned by Tormund Giantsbane in the comments, [this document has nice information on the topic auf automatic dependencies](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)